# How do I disable Cookies on Selenium Chrome?

Tags: python, selenium

I have been looking around stackoverflow and I cannot find a solution to this. The solutions I did find were apparently old.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\amete\Documents\Python\Code\Web test.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\amete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\amete\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
PATH = r"C:\Users\amete\Documents\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
print (driver.title)

search = driver.find_element_by_id("input")
search.send_keys("One Piece")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: If it did not work, was there any error ? were cookies not disabled ?

Comment: The error is on the edited post

The website I want to load doesn't load.

My original code is there too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks okay, but the error says  `chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH` , right ?

Which means instead of :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

you need to do this :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

To block all the cookies

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", 2);
```

To block all the third party cookies

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", 1);
options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.cookie_controls_mode", 1);
```

Comment: This give me an error code:
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax